# Update MySQL row without removing the existing value with string and text using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, sql-update

The goal is: Update value in row without removing existing value.

For example in column `user_saw` I have: "156,"

So after Update should be: "156,300,"

Now after Update is: "300,"  ("156," disappears)

```
$data['id'] = 300;
$db->Query("UPDATE `m_notifications` SET `user_saw`='$data['id']',',' 
WHERE `site_id`='".$sit['id']."' AND `user_id`='".$sit['user']."'");
```

Comment: That's because you are using the wrong options with SET

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$db->Query("UPDATE m_notifications  
            SET user_saw=CONCAT(user_saw,{$data['id']},',') 
            WHERE site_id={$sit['id']} AND user_id={$sit['user']}") ;
```

However, better use prepared statements, it is an ENORMOUS safety risk not to do.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I notice I sometimes get downvoted for answering the question as the OP intended and add safety warnings to my answer. However, always without explanation. Is this because these down voters don't read my safety warning and feel it is unsafe? Or do they feel that I should not provide an answer without the safety implemented? I am curious. I feel you should answer as OP intended, and add a safety warning, and not implement the safety yourself unasked in your answer. Any opinions? Especially the negative voter? I mean, I cannot imaging it is because I suggested a CONCAT... :D

Comment: Generally speaking you mention the benefits of a more secure method, and answer in a way that fits their system. Answering with something that the whole rest of the system doesn't use isn't even always a good upgrade. It can make their system confusing or even buggy depending on the switch.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // SELECT column FROM table WHERE site_id = $sit['id'] && user_id = $sit['user'] 
    // result is $json
    $arr = json_decode($json); 
    if(!in_array($data['id'], $arr){
     $arr[] = $data['id'];
     $json = json_encode($arr); 
     // UPDATE table SET column = $json WHERE site_id = $sit['id'] && user_id = $sit['user']
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Good answer also, but I prefer the first one.

Comment: Yeah no problem! I just like this because it makes sure each $data['id'] is only in there once. The answer above would allow a notification to be put in there more than once. But if it works for you and what you're doing, that's good :)